# Filter collection with optional values

Tags: javascript

I have a problem: I know how to use `Array.prototype.filter`, but I can't imagine how to filter out items with optional keys. For example:

```
[
    {item: 1, paths: {category: "country", name: "England", access: 2},
    {item: 3, paths: {category: "country", name: "Russia", access: 2},
    {item: 2, paths: {category: "country", name: "Portugal", access: 0}
]
```

And I'd like to filter them out by paths optionally, let's say by shape of object like that:

```
{category: "country", access: 2}
```

How can I achieve such a thing?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: It should return array with England and Russia.

Comment: you mean you'd like the filtering criteria to be dynamic?  If so, I mis-read the question in that you weren't sure that each entry would have the properties you wish to filter on for my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom comparator in filter that compares all the values of your comparator object with the item like

```js
const data = [
 {item: 1, paths: {category: "country", name: "England", access: 2}},
 {item: 3, paths: {category: "country", name: "Russia", access: 2}},
 {item: 2, paths: {category: "country", name: "Portugal", access: 0}}
]

const comparator = {category: "country", access: 2};

const compareObjectKeys = (comparator, item) => {
    return Object.keys(comparator).every(key => {
        return item.paths[key] === comparator[key];
    })
}
const res = data.filter(item => {
   return compareObjectKeys(comparator, item);
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Whether this is what he meant or not, it's a useful snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You could get key and value and compair against the object for filtering.

```js
var data = [{ item: 1, paths: { category: "country", name: "England", access: 2 } }, { item: 3, paths: { category: "country", name: "Russia", access: 2 } }, { item: 2, paths: { category: "country", name: "Portugal", access: 0 } }], 
    filter = { category: "country", access: 2 },
    result = data.filter(({ paths }) =>
        Object.entries(filter).every(([k, v]) => paths[k] === v));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```